# Rails 4 querying through has_many relationships with nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-many

I am looking to find an array of Authors represented by a given Agent, but only Authors who have more than 3 books. 
  **For example**: if Authors 1, 5 and 7 have more than three  books but Authors 2, 3, and 6 have only 1 my query should only return Authors 1, 5,7.

```
class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
    has_many :authors
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :agent
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
    belongs_to :agent
end
```

This is what I've tried.  I'm stumped

agents_controller.rb

```
def show
    @agent = Agent.find(params[:id])
    @authors = @agent.authors
    @books = @authors.books
    @popular = @authors.where(@books.count > 3)
end
```

Nothing works.  I feel like I should be able to iterate and then find distinct or unique @author_ids in collections of @books...but I haven't been able to find how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Author.joins(:books)
  .where(agent_id: params[:id])
  .group(:id)
  .having('count(books.id) > 3')
```

This will return an ActiveRecord relation of `Author`s

**PS:**
You also might want to consider a [`counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache), you'll be able to query without doing calculations on the database.

Add a field called `books_count` in the author table, then in the books model add this change:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author, counter_cache: true
end
```

This way the query would be much easier

```
Author.where(agent_id: params[:id]).where('books_count > 3')
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like..

```
Agent.find(params[:id).
  author.select("authors.*, count(books.id) as books_count").joins(:books).
  group_by("authors.id").
  having("books_count > 3")
```

### UPDATE:

```
Agent.find(params[:id]).authors.select("authors.*, count(books.id) as books_count").joins(:books).group("authors.id").having("books_count > 3")
```

Comment: it says 'undefined method `author'

Comment: oh, sorry,  my bad, I will to fix that

Comment: hmmm....now I'm getting this :" PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "books_count" does not exist
LINE 1: ...agent_id" = $1 GROUP BY authors.id HAVING books_cou..."  ...I tried removing books_count and just having count(books.id), but that turns up an empty array

Comment: oh, man... how am I supposed to you are using pgsql.. you should have mentioned it in the question. see Andrey's answer. I dunno pgsql

Answer (score 0):

This works for Postgres:

```
Agent.find(params[:id]).authors.select("authors.*").joins(:books).group("authors.id").having("count(*) > 3")
```

Comment: Yes, Mohammad's answer is better. You'll only need 'authors.id' in group() clause.